# Pass variable to function as reference

Tags: flash, actionscript, reference, actionscript-2

I am having a hard time passing a variable to a function as a reference. Here is the part of my code which is the troublemaker:

```
onMouseDown = function ():Void
{
    mouseListener(openCategory, [control[current]]);
};

function mouseListener(callback:Function, callbackParams:Array):Void
{
    for (var index in categories)
    {
        var category:MovieClip = categories[index];
        if (category.hitTest(root._xmouse, root._ymouse))
        {
                control[current] = category;
                callback.apply(null, callbackParams);
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I want to happen is that the function stored in `callback` receives a reference to `control[current]` or at least the most current value of it. What actually happens is the value of `control[current]` is passed to `mouseListener`.

How can I get this functionality to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primitives in AS are never passed by reference, you would need to box it into a complex type and pass the boxed value - these are always passed by reference. In your case, pass the entire `control`, whatever that is, and read `control[current]` inside `callback`.